# Strange browser behavior: Img loses aspect ratio on resize, regains on refresh

Tags: image, responsive-design, css, aspect-ratio

I am creating a horizontal list of images with descriptions that scale with browser height. The descriptions are fixed-width and the images preserve their aspect ratio. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<main>
  <ol id="projects">
  <li class="project">
      <div class="preview"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" /></div>
      <div class="desc"></div>
  </li><li class="project">
          <div class="preview"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" /></div>
      <div class="desc"></div>
  </li><li class="project">
      <div class="preview"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" /></div>
      <div class="desc"></div>
  </li><li class="project">
          <div class="preview"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" /></div>
      <div class="desc"></div>
  </li>
</ol>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,main,#projects{
    height:100%;
}

#projects {
  width:1000px;
  float:left;
  overflow:visible;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.project {
  height:100%;   
  display:inline-block;
}

.desc{
    background-color:#afa;
    float:right;
    width:10em;
    height:100%;
}

.preview{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}

.preview img{
    height:100%;
    min-width:10px;
}
```

Here's [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLf0frwh/)

When the page is first loaded, the images behave as desired. However, as soon as the viewport is resized vertically, they lose their aspect ratio. However, if one reloads the page with the new viewport dimensions, the images behave correctly again. See the GIF:

[image: GIF of the issue]

Is this my error, a browser error, or some combination of the two? Is there an alternative way to achieve my goal?

Comment: will the internal images always be square? or a fixed ratio of height to width for all of them?

Comment: Ideally the design would be flexible enough to handle a variety of aspect ratios. I'd rather not bake the ratio into the design.

Comment: This seems similar to another issue I looked at some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528302/firefox-trouble-a-float-container-is-longer-than-the-child/24528799#24528799 Chrome tends to have issues with this sort of thing, apparently, but I can't tell at a glance if your case falls under unspecified behavior like that one does.

Comment: FYI: forcing a reflow with a $('html').hide.show(0) on resize is a stopgap solution. I think this might be a webkit bug